# Why does Google Now display my "Home" and "Work" locations inaccurately?

Tags: google, geolocation, google-now

I'm in my home all day, every day, as are my internet-capable devices such as phone, Chromebook, etcetera, etcetera. Yet, when I click the magic wand at the bottom of Google Now (settings), it displays my home address and work address as two different places, both of-which I've never even been, muchless worked or lived.

Any ideas why this would be happening? Anyone seeing anything remotely similar?

Comment: T-Mobile, LG Optimus, Android 4.1.2 | P76920h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Now is guessing, based on where and when you spend your time.

If it's wrong, simply edit it. Once manually set it won't guess anymore.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the fields and Google Now said the changed would take place tomorrow.